# Traefik custom error middleware for HTTP status 502 doesn’t work

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, traefik

I would like to serve custom error pages for common HTTP error codes. I was following [this tutorial](https://imandrea.me/blog/traefik-custom-404/). For this purpose, I created the following `docker-compose.yml` file to test the functionality. It consists of:

1. `errorPageHandler` which is a nginx server which is able to return static HTML pages (`404.html` and `502.html`).
2. `whoami1` which routes the request to port 80 of `traefik/whoami` image
3. `whoami2` which routes the request to non-existent port 81 of `traefik/whoami` image which results in 502 - Bad Gateway

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  errorPageHandler:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    volumes:
      - "./ErrorPages:/usr/share/nginx/ErrorPages"
      - "./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        # enable Traefik for this service
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"

        # router (catches all requests with lowest possible priority)
        - "traefik.http.routers.error-router.rule=HostRegexp(`{catchall:.*}`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.error-router.priority=1"
        - "traefik.http.routers.error-router.middlewares=error-pages-middleware"

        # middleware
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.error-pages-middleware.errors.status=400-599"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.error-pages-middleware.errors.service=error-pages-service"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.error-pages-middleware.errors.query=/{status}.html"

        # service
        - "traefik.http.services.error-pages-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
  
  whoami1:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        # enable Traefik for this service
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"

        # router
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami1.rule=HostRegexp(`whoami1.local`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami1.service=whoami1"
        
        # service
        - "traefik.http.services.whoami1.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.http.services.whoami1.loadbalancer.server.scheme=http"
        
  whoami2:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        # enable Traefik for this service
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"

        # router
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami2.rule=HostRegexp(`whoami2.local`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami2.service=whoami2"
        
        # service
        - "traefik.http.services.whoami2.loadbalancer.server.port=81" # purposely wrong port
        - "traefik.http.services.whoami2.loadbalancer.server.scheme=http"

networks:
  traefik-net:
    external: true
    name: traefik-net
```

Folder `ErrorPages` contains two static HTML files, `404.html` and `502.html`. Content of `default.conf` is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    error_page  404    /404.html;
    error_page  502    /502.html;

    location / {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/ErrorPages;
        internal;
    }
}
```

I added the following entries to my `hosts` file (`172.15.16.17` is IP of the server where Traefik and all of the mentioned services are deployed):

```
172.15.16.17 error404.local
172.15.16.17 whoami1.local
172.15.16.17 whoami2.local
```

My observations:

1. When I visit `http://error404.local`, Traefik routes the request to nginx and `404.html` is returned. This is expected behavior because `http://error404.local` doesn't match any of the routes defined in Traefik.
2. When I visit `http://whoami1.local`, Traefik routes request to `whoami1` service and information about container is displayed on the page (expected behavior).
3. When I visit `http://whoami2.local`, Traefik doesn't route request to nginx service, but it displays its default `Bad Gateway` page. Why doesn't it route the request to the nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traefik routers (whoami1 and whoami2) needs to use the error middleware that you defined

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/errorpages/
[Traefik error middleware docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq7BW.png)

So add the following labels to their respective containers

```
- "traefik.http.whoami1.middlewares=error-pages-middleware"

- "traefik.http.whoami2.middlewares=error-pages-middleware"
```

the Traefik dashboard will show that the routes are using the middleware (refer image) [One of my routes from my traefik dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQpfq.png)

Another option would be to add the middleware to the entrypoint so that all routes use the error middleware (Add this to traefik container compose)

```
command:
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.http.middlewares=error-pages-middleware@docker"
```

Comment: Thank you. How can we distinguish between HTTP error code 403 being generated by Traefik middleware (IP whitelist) or purposely by our application (we show our custom application error page with request ID, login info, etc.)? We want to route request to nginx only if 403 was thrown by Traefik.

Comment: @AleksVujic did you ever find a way to do this? I am also trying to only override Traefik's built-in error pages, but no luck so far...